# Como posso fazer "Inner Join"

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

Preiso de fazer `inner join` com 2 tabelas da base de dados, digamos que uma se chama *equipamento* e outra *tipo_indicador*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irei te dar um exemplo utilizando Linq com Lambda Expression.

```
database.equipamento.Join(database.tipo_indicador,
                          equipamento => equipamento.CAMPOREFERENTEJOIN,
                          tipo_indicador => tipo_indicador.CAMPOREFERENTEJOIN,
                          (equipamento, tipo_indicador) => new
                          {
                              //Aqui vão os campos que você gostaria de retornar no select. 
                              //No meu caso estou pegando todos os campos das duas tabelas,
                              //pois não estou especificando os campos. 
                              //Caso queira alguns campos específicos, é só especificar, 
                              //por exemplo: equipamento.NomeEquipamento

                              equipamento,
                              tipo_indicador
                          }).ToList();
```

Comment: muito obrigao, era mesmo isso que eu precisava!!

Answer (score 2):

Usando Linq

```
from t1 in db.equipamento 
join t2 in db.tipo_indicador on t1.field equals t2.field
select new { t1.field2, t2.field3}
```

Comment: obrigado, mas só não sei 1 coisa agora que é se eu tiver um campo que queira no equipamento e vários no tipo_indicador e eu só vou buscar o tipo_indicador se coincidir com o campo no equipamento

Answer (score 0):

Usando o T-SQL seria

```
SELECT Tabela1.Campo1,Tabela2.Campo1,Tabela2.Campo2
FROM Tabela1
INNER JOIN Tabela2 ON Tabela1.Campo1=Tabela2.Campo2
```